# How do i get the bones to look like this?

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I want to change the bone that i have to the ones that this Freddy Fazbear model has, the website you sent didnt help :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to achieve? Please edit your question and explain what is it that you want to do.

Comment: Also see if this helps https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/armatures/bones/properties/display.html

Comment: I changed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Under the properties of the armature you will find display section giving the option on how you want your armature displayed (stick,...). You can also add custom shapes to the bone so that it appears as a box, sphere or any other shape you create.